# Unix time conversion with select in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have loaded datingDF that looks like;

```
+---+--------+------+---+---------+
|Uid|Zip_Code|Height|Age|Meet_Date|
+---+--------+------+---+---------+
|  1|   90117|   171| 22|881250949|
|  2|   90340|   168| 24|891717742|
|  3|   92552|   170| 38|878887116|
|  4|   90455|   175| 41|880606923|
|  5|   91045|   165| 25|886397596|
|  6|   90050|   172| 32|884182806|
|  7|   90110|   166| 27|881171488|
|  8|   90340|   169| 49|891628467|
|  9|   91040|   175| 51|886324817|
| 10|   90320|   169| 32|883603013|
+---+--------+------+---+---------+
```

Meet_Date is represented in Unix time in seconds since 1/1/1970 UTC. The schema defined is;

```
val datingSchema=StructType(Array(
  StructField("Uid",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("Zip_Code",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("Height",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("Age",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("Meet_Date",IntegerType,true))
)
```

I want to list the DF in the order of yyyy converted from Unix time. I ran the query below but got error about String type?;

```
scala> val df1=datingDF.select("Uid","Zip_Code","Height","Age",from_unixtime(col("Meet_Date"), "yyyy")).orderBy("Meet_Date")
<console>:31: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1, U2, U3, U4, U5](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1], c2: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U2], c3: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U3], c4: 
org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U4], c4: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U5])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(U1, U2, U3, U4, U5)] <and>
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, String, String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
       val df1=datingDF.select("Uid","Zip_Code","Height","Age",from_unixtime(col("Meet_Date"), "yyyy")).orderBy("Meet_Date")
                       ^
```

I know I've converted the Unix time correctly;

```
scala> val df2=datingDF.select(from_unixtime(col("Meet_Date"), "yyyy")).orderBy("Meet_Date")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [from_unixtime(Meet_Date, yyyy): string]

scala> df2.show(5)
+------------------------------+                                                     
|from_unixtime(Meet_Date, yyyy)|
+------------------------------+
|                          1997|
|                          1997|
|                          1997|
|                          1997|
|                          1997|
+------------------------------+
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I also tried using the DateType in my schema for the Meet_Date with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message : `cannot be applied to (String, String, String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)` we see that it is the type of what you put in the select expression which is wrong. And if you look just before it says that select can be applied on  `(col: String,cols: String*)` and `(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)`.
So try this instead :

```
val df1=datingDF.select(col("Uid"),col("Zip_Code"),col("Height"),col("Age"),from_unixtime(col("Meet_Date"), "yyyy")).orderBy("Meet_Date")
```

Comment: If I wanted my schema for date to be DateType (changing the IntegerType to DateType for the Meet_Date column). And I rerun the same query;
```
val df1=datingDF.select(col("Uid"),col("Zip_Code"),col("Height"),col("Age"),from_unixtime(col("Meet_Date"), "yyyy")).orderBy("Meet_Date")
```
I get the following error;
```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'from_unixtime(`Meet_Date`, 'yyyy')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires bigint type, however, '`Meet_Date`' is of date type.
```